# Parallel computing in R: how to choose cores

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, rparallel

In R, I using packages "doParallel" and "foreach" to parallel computing. Recently, I am running the program in HPC. It has four nodes, and each node has 16 processors. My R program only needs 4 processors. But the HPC always assigns the program to one node occupying all 16 processors. So I cannot run any other program in that node then. **How to choose the self-defined number of processors in one node? And how to choose the processors which are not running program in one node?**
I use

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(MASS)
registerDoParallel(makeCluster(4))
```

I only need to use 4 processors. But the hpc always assigns one program to all processors in one nodes(actually the program is running in 4 processors).
**For example**, a node has 16 processors. I have four programs that each of them needs four cores. What should I do to put four programs in one node?

Comment: How were you registering your parallel backend previously?  Doesn't `registerDoParallel` allow you to specify the number of processors/cores?

Comment: I use
{library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(MASS)
registerDoParallel(makeCluster(4))}

Comment: I do not how to put code in the comment. So I added the program in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`parallel::detectCores()` should give you the number of cores you have.

The idiom I usually use is somme combination of `parallel::detectCores()` with

```
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)


num_cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(num_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# parallel code here

# stop cores/cluster
stopCluster(cl)
registerDoSEQ()
```

Comment: Yes, I did that. But the hpc always assigns one program to all processors in one nodes(actually the program is running in 4 processors).

Comment: "So I cannot run any other program in that node then"

does this mean if you do a `top` or `htop` it shows all the cores active at 100%?